# RSA public key same across all clients or different?

Tags: rsa

I understand that public key is a pair of $(e, N)$ where $N$ is product of two primes and $e$ is encryption key.

I understand that $N$ is usually unique for an entity. For example, Facebook, Google, etc. have $1028$ or $2048$ bit $N$ that they publish.

What about $e$? Is it also unique or do these entity give different $e$ to different clients/customers? Does it changes from one session to other for same client?

Answer (score 4):

The full public key is usually published, not just $N$. The public key consists of $N$ and $e$ + meta data (ASN.1 encoding, object identifier for RSA, etc.). How the public key is encoded depends of course to the protocol.

If it is shared for e.g. transport security it is usually part of a certificate that also contains subject, issuer, validity period, key usuage etc. and of course the signature of the issuer over the certificate. This makes it possible not just to retrieve the public key but also to find out if the key should be trusted and how the key should be used.

Generally the public key uses the Fourth prime of Fermat (F4) as public exponent $e$. This makes public key operations somewhat faster and it allows for easy key pair generation. Some cryptographic libraries or runtimes restrict the size or value of $e$, so choosing a different value is not recommended. Still, most libraries will accept an $e$ that is, for instance, smaller than 4 bytes (i.e. $2^{32}$ for unsigned or $2^{31}$ for signed integers). Using F4 is generally *not* a requirement in protocols. That said, using anything different may cause compatibility issues.

Having a different $e$ doesn't affect the security of RSA, as long as it is relative prime to $φ(pq)$.

---

Notes:

- Using 1024 bit RSA is not recommended anymore. Using a 2048 bit or higher key size is highly recommended.
- $N$ directly depends on the two (or more) random primes used to generate the key pair so $N$ is always fully unique, making the public key fully unique - regardless of $e$. A hash over $N$ is generally used as *key ID* or *fingerprint of the key pair*. $N$ is part of both the public- and the private key.

Answer (score 2):

The public key is $(e,N)$ and $e$ is also fixed. It certainly does not change from session to session.

Comment: is e same for all customers/clients ? Is it also 1024 or 2048 bit long?

Comment: $e$ is usually $2^{16} + 1$, an exact 17-bit number

Comment: Thanks @cypherfox. Adding here link from math stack exchange https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16901/modular-exponentation-for-rsa-why-is-216-1-commonly-chosen

Answer (score 2):

The value of $e$ is encoded along with the modulus $N$. Since $e$ is usually short, it does not add much to the total size. For instance, the current RSA certificate uses by `www.google.com`, in hexadecimal, contains the following encoded public key:

```
  281:d=3  hl=4 l= 271 prim:    BIT STRING        
      0000 - 00 30 82 01 0a 02 82 01-01 00 bb eb 21 f9 e5 56   .0..........!..V
      0010 - 9d e9 b2 18 55 a3 2d 4c-72 5c b8 49 4c ff 14 a7   ....U.-Lr\.IL...
      0020 - 6b 03 6d b2 de 0c 8e 93-1d 9a a8 56 d0 48 e7 06   k.m........V.H..
      0030 - f9 5f 1f 58 fb 25 f1 df-d7 47 bb 20 33 14 96 78   ._.X.%...G. 3..x
      0040 - dc 1d b8 14 e8 14 ca d4-2a d0 e4 75 31 26 59 d9   ........*..u1&Y.
      0050 - 9c 31 d4 23 40 8d d0 ea-f2 70 94 8b 1e 37 ff d9   .1.#@....p...7..
      0060 - 6d 8f e2 34 9c 5a 44 a6-66 9d 95 0d 6a a0 81 fc   m..4.ZD.f...j...
      0070 - b8 e8 f7 c7 09 5b 38 e5-f4 ac cb 69 37 c5 18 51   .....[8....i7..Q
      0080 - 56 38 6f 4d 9e a0 98 c9-39 ca b6 29 22 ca aa b8   V8oM....9..)"...
      0090 - 66 1f da ca 99 9b 72 0b-b1 f1 b0 3f 32 4f 8c 26   f.....r....?2O.&
      00a0 - 83 49 8e 8b 9c 23 75 43-1b 08 67 48 8e d8 10 cd   .I...#uC..gH....
      00b0 - 2d fb 50 48 f3 6d a7 be-b3 51 e8 cc 8f b3 17 ce   -.PH.m...Q......
      00c0 - ae 8f fa 84 6d e9 42 bb-21 b0 15 7a 35 5b 3c e5   ....m.B.!..z5[<.
      00d0 - 00 cc 31 3d c7 72 67 f9-ab 43 3e b5 af 53 f2 55   ..1=.rg..C>..S.U
      00e0 - 67 f1 b1 42 a1 30 19 5f-af 86 24 82 ff 2e 07 8a   g..B.0._..$.....
      00f0 - 64 67 01 dc 22 ee 0f 94-06 e3 95 18 38 e9 d9 6d   dg..".......8..m
      0100 - bc d6 45 a6 d1 b4 f3 ea-b4 35 02 03 01 00 01      ..E......5.....
```

This is an extract of the decoding of the certificate with `openssl asn1parse`. This reads as follows:

- `00`: the number of bits to ignore in the last byte (it is a `BIT STRING`, though formally it does not necessarily contain an integral number of *bytes*, although in this case it does).
- `30 82 01 0a`: a `SEQUENCE` that contains 266 bytes.
- `02 82 01 01`: header for an `INTEGER` value of length 257 bytes (that's the modulus $N$).
- `00 bb eb 21 ...`: the 257 bytes that encode the value of $N$. Not that the first byte is zero, so the mathematical value actually fits on exactly 256 bytes. The value is then a 2048-bit integer (it is lower than $2^{2048}$ but greater than $2^{2047}$).
- After the modulus value remain five bytes: `02 03 01 00 01`. This is the second `INTEGER` value in the `SEQUENCE`; the numerical value first over three bytes: `01 00 01`. in decimal, that's 65537.

**The use of 65537** (also often called "F4") is *traditional*, and apparently comes from a choice by Phil Zimmerman (creator of PGP) in the early 1990s, for reasons which are a bit confused. There is a long-standing by unsubstantiated myth that 65537 is "safer" than the more efficient value $e = 3$. Analysis shows that there is no extra safety (65537 is "better" than 3 only when using "textbook RSA", i.e. only half of the algorithm, which is in any case a very bad idea). However, myths have their own momentum, and that one is deeply entrenched, which is why most implementations of RSA default to 65537. It does not matter much in practice, at least in Web contexts (experience on low-power smartcards may differ).

It is not a problem if the value of $e$ is shared between public keys. It is not mandatory either.

*Theoretically*, a key owner could have a modulus $N$ and use several different values of $e$. There is no known reason to do that, though, and it would complicate some usages. For instance, the public key of a Web server, including $e$, is contained in its *certificate*, which is signed by a Certification Authority. If $e$ was to be changed, then the contents of the certificate would vary, and the CA would have to issue (sign) it again.